# fastest way to Filter, Order and split in pages method

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, linq

I want to get data from a database, to show on a page. There is a huge amount of rows in the table, so I'm using pages to avoid having to scroll forever.

I have functionnalities to search words (no specific columns), order by any column, and obviously change the page size and which page I am on.

I could, in theory, just ask the database for everything (SELECT * FROM myTable), send it to my html view, and work through the data entirely in javascript. The problem is, there is so much data that this is extremely slow using my structure (page controller calls my main logic, which calls a webservice, which calls the database), sometimes waiting up to 20 seconds for the original load of the page. After it's loaded, the javascript is usually fast.

Or, I could do most of that work in the controller, using Linq. I could also do the work in the webservice (it's mine), still in Linq. Or, I could straight away use WHERE, ORDER BY, COUNT, and a bunch of dynamic SQL requests so that I get instantly what I want from the database. But any of those forces me to refresh the page every time one of the parameters changes.

So I'm wondering about performance. For example, which is faster between:

```
var listObjects = ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM myTable");
return listObjects.Where(x => x.field == word).OrderBy(x => x.field);
```

and

```
var listObjects = ExecuteSQL("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field = :param1 ORDER BY field", word);
return listObjects;
```

And in what specific situations would using the different methods I've mentioned be better or worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You want to do the work of selecting a block (pagefull) of *data* on your *dataserver*.  That's it's job; it knows how to do it best.

So, forget the `ExecuteSQL`.  You are pretty much shutting down everything's ability to help you.   Try LINQ:

```
  var page = (from m in MyTable
              where m.field == param1
             orderby m.field
             select m)
             .Skip((nPage-1)*pageLength).Take(pageLength);
```

That will generate the exact SQL to tell the Data Server to return just the rows you want.